What did Alfred Austin mean by “poetry”?
In an essay on Robert Browning, Alfred Austin (later poet laureate) stated, repeatedly and emphatically, that Browning did not write, and was unable to write, poetry:

Now, Mr. Browning rarely, if ever, thinks in poetry. His thoughts are often tremendously deep thoughts—deeper than any Mr. Tennyson is ever visited by; but they reach him in the guise of prose, and, so reaching him, quit him in substantially the same form, though draped on their reappearance in the disguise of verse.
Alfred Austin (1870). The Poetry of the Period, page 46. London: Richard Bentley.


It must not be supposed that I quote this passage with approbation. Not only do I think it not poetry, but I think it detestable gibberish, even if I look at it as prose.
Austin, page 53.

The passage that Austin says is “not poetry” is an extract from Browning’s Sordello, quoted on pages 52–53 (albeit with one missing line). This extract is written in rhyming couplets of regular iambic pentameter, and consists of an extended metaphor comparing the poet and reader to two brothers, one of whom can sympathetically understand the meaning of the other. Now, everyone’s taste is different, so it is fair to dislike Browning’s poetry. But calling something “not poetry” is not a matter of taste or opinion, it’s a matter of definition, and clearly Austin means something more specific by the word than the usual dictionary definition (for example, the OED: “Composition in verse or some comparable patterned arrangement of language in which the expression of feelings and ideas is given intensity by the use of distinctive style and rhythm”).
Under these circumstances, one might expect Austin to justify himself by explaining what he means by “poetry”, and what additional qualities he demands of the term beyond those found in the dictionary. But what he gives us is a footnote admitting that he is unable to do this:

Hence the difficulty of defining poetry, just as there exists the well-known difficulty of defining life. But just as despite the latter difficulty we can always say in any particular instance what is not life, so despite the former one we can say in any particular instance what is not poetry.
Austin, page 58.

What was going on here? Why was Austin so emphatic about the application of a term that he admits he could not pin down? If Austin was unable to explain what he meant, can we figure it out from his critical remarks, or those of like-minded contemporaries?
Update. Obviously it’s possible that Austin was just throwing insults, and didn’t have any kind of theory about poetry. However, since he was a poet himself, and respected sufficiently in some quarters to win the laureateship, I’d prefer to see an answer that takes Austin’s claims seriously before (or instead of) dismissing them.

You will find all sorts of objections to all sorts of works that consist of saying "This is not X" when they mean "This is bad X."


What was going on here?

There's nothing complex. Quite simply, Austin is expressing personal dislike of Browning's poetic writings. He has taken against them and is justifying his decision to himelf and anyone who will listen. You can tell that the cry is emotional as he appears to give no precise faults. (I haven't read the article, and I don't think it would help to do so.)
You can sum it up in "I know what I like and Browning's poetry is not it."
Austin does not need to define anything in this polemic. He perhaps justifies it recalling Dr Johnson "I do not have to be a carpenter to say that the table wobbles." (or some-such.)
There is an article a by Daric Gill Studios, entitled "That's not Art!" in which we have

We like to think that when we say, “That’s Not Art!” we are stating something of personal or scholarly merit; As if to say, “I know what art is… and that isn’t it.” However, that’s rarely what we are actually trying to say. The aim of this article is to help artists, musicians, writers, and the like find a mutual navigation point from which a more constructive resolution can be formed.

Perhaps Austin should have considered its arguments.

Austin was later able to define what he meant by “poetry”:

I think it will be well for us to have a clear idea in our minds as to what is Poetry. I have seen many definitions, none of which have quite satisfied me, and therefore I must run the risk, no slight one, I am aware, of offering a definition of my own. In the Gospel according to St. Mark, we are told that Peter, James, and John were taken by our Lord up to a high mountain, and that He was transfigured before them.† I trust I shall not be thought irreverent if I suggest that Poetry is Transfiguration, the transfiguration of the Actual or the Real into the Ideal, at a lofty elevation, through the medium of melodious or nobly sounding verse.
Alfred Austin (1904). ‘The Growing Distaste for the Higher Kinds of Poetry’. In The Fortnightly Review 447 (1 March 1904), page 383.
† Mark 9:2.

Of course, this definition might not be exactly what Austin had in mind (albeit inarticulately or unconsciously) thirty years previously, but let’s assume, for the sake of argument, that it is close enough. And we’ll see below that Austin still had Browning very much in mind in the later essay.
So, unlike Aristotle, who says that poetry “must represent men either as better than in real life, or as worse, or as they are” (Poetics 1448a), Austin requires that poetry only present things as better than they are. It also seems to follow, if we accept Aristotle’s claim that “Comedy aims at representing men as worse”, that in Austin’s view there is no such thing as comic poetry. Certainly Austin’s first example, in the 1904 essay, of a work that is “not poetry”, is a comic pair of stanzas from Wordsworth’s ‘Simon Lee, the Old Huntsman’.
It’s easy to see how this would lead Austin to exclude Browning’s general body of work from the category “poetry”, since Browning was fascinated with grotesque, fallible, hypocritical, and corrupt characters, and what they might have had to say for themselves. However, this does not explain Austin’s objection to the particular passage he quoted from Sordello in 1870, because Browning in this passage is transfiguring in exactly the way that Austin demands, that is, taking the real (the communication of ideas from a poet to a reader) and idealizing it as one brother speaking to another.
So the objection must come from the other requirement, that poetry be written in “lofty”, “melodious” or “nobly sounding” diction. Let’s compare the passage from Browning’s Sordello quoted in Austin (1870) with the example of “very beautiful Poetry” in Austin (1904):

                                                        To-day
Takes in account the work of Yesterday:
Has not the world a Past now, its adept
Consults ere he dispense with or accept
New aids? a single touch more may enhance,
A touch less turned to insignificance
Those structures’ symmetry the past has strewed
The world with, once so bare. Leave the mere rude
Explicit details! ’t is but brother’s speech,
We need, speech where an accent’s change gives each
The other’s soul—no speech to understand
By former audience: need was then to expand,
Expatiate—hardly were we brothers! true—
Nor I lament my small remove from you,
Nor reconstruct what stands already.
Robert Browning (1840). Sordello, book 5, lines 627–641. Quoted in Austin (1870), pages 52–53. Line 630 was omitted by Austin, but I have restored it here as the argument is hard to follow without it.


At the corner of Wood Street, when daylight appears,
Hangs a thrush that sings loud, it has sung for three years;
Poor Susan has passed by the spot, and has heard,
In the silence of morning, the song of the Bird.
William Wordsworth (1799). ‘Poor Susan’, lines 1–4. Quoted in Austin (1904), page 384.

These two works are very different in subject and style: Browning’s subject is abstract (his theory of poetic communication), Wordsworth’s is concrete and natural (the song of a thrush); Browning presents an argument for his theory, Wordsworth a description of his subject; Browning’s complex concepts require multiple enjambed lines to express; Wordsworth’s are simple enough to be complete within a single end-stopped line; Browning's long words give the lines a scholarly and difficult style, Wordsworth's short and simple words could be understood by a child.
Later in the 1904 essay Austin presents some passages from another of Browning’s poems, ‘Bishop Blougram’s Apology’ (1855), and explains how, in his opinion, it “is not Poetry at all”.

Is there any Transfiguration here? Are we taken up to a high place? Is the Actual transformed into the Ideal by imaginative, or even by musical, or nobly-sounding verse? Is that Poetry? Yet I have not quoted it at random. I have extracted it from a most eulogistic notice, in which are cited and extolled passages after passages of a similar character.† The bulk of the writer’s‡ verse is written after much the same fashion, and this, we have been told, and are still being told, is great Poetry, when of a truth, whatever else it may be, it is not Poetry at all.
Austin (1904), page 388.
† The unnamed “notice” must be Josiah Flew’s Studies in Browning (1904), for Austin has juxtaposed three passages quoted by Flew: lines 580–581 and lines 588–591 on page 111 and lines 243–254 on page 112. Austin gives the passages in the order they were quoted by Flew, and not in the order they appear in the poem: this suggests that he had not read the poem, or at least did not re-read it when writing the 1904 essay. ‡ It is notable that Austin does not name Browning here, even though by 1904 Browning had been dead for fifteen years. Perhaps Austin was still smarting from Browning’s lampoon, ‘Of Pacchiarotto, and How He Worked in Distemper’ (1876).

As in the case of Sordello, the passages from ‘Bishop Blougram’s Apology’ are complex arguments about abstract ideas, not simple descriptions of the natural world. And Blougram is a fallible and hypocritical character, far from the “Ideal” that Austin requires.
